# guarding a critical section with a mutex

Tags: multithreading, critical-section

Let's say that I have a shared object that has a piece of code protected with a critical section and more than 1 thread are accessing the object for read/write. When a thread is inside the critical section the other threads are waiting. Once the thread gets out of the CS then the OS gives access to any of the waiting threads.

If I am confined to only one process, does the CS alone is a good protection for the shared object?

I ask because I have seen on the web that the right way to do it is to use a kernel object (ex: mutex, semaphone) to guard the CS. A thread wishing to use the shared resource needs to obtain the mutex/semaphore first with a WaitForSingleObject type of function. If a mutex is used then only one of then can access the resource. Once the mutex is obtained then the thread Enters the CS, does what is supposed to do, then Leave the CS and Releases the mutex. Then the OS allows any other waiting thread to obtain the mutex and so on and so forth.

But isn't is the same as using only the CS?

Also, using a mutex is supposed to be significantly slower than using a CS alone. The only problem I see of using only a CS is that if the thread crashes inside the CS then the other threads may never access the shared resource.

Is there any other reason why this approach is better?
thanks in advance

Comment: Should this be moved to [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I have never seen any code that does what you say you've seen. Can you point to some code that acquires a mutex or sempahore and then acquires a critical section with the same scope? I suspect you may just be misreading or misunderstanding that code and that's the source of your confusion. (It's also possible you're confusing two different uses of the term "critical section". One meaning a particular synchronization primitive and one meaning a region of code protected by mutex-like synchronization.)

Comment: Thank you david, I mean the CSection windows structure (InitializeCS, EnterCS, LeaveCS, DeleteCS). Could it be that I misinterpreted what I read?

Comment: A Windows CriticalSection IS a process-bound mutex.  It works fine within a process.  There is no need for any further protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're discussing some Windows-specific terminology in a way that's getting it mixed up with some general computer science terminology.

In computer science the term "critical section" is used for areas of code that must run exclusively (usually due to data sharing).  In Windows, there's a synchronization object called `CRITICAL_SECTION` that can be used to provide exclusive access to areas of execution. Another attribute of a `CRITICAL_SECTION` object on Windows is that it is limited to being used within a single process.

In computer science, the term 'mutex' is often used to describe an object that can be used to provide synchronization among parallel or cncurrent threads of execution.  In Windows, there is also a mutex object which can be created with the `CreateMutex()` function (which returns a `HANDLE` representing the mutex).  That object can be used to synchronize access among threads in the same or different processes, so it can be used similar to a `CRITICAL_SECTION` (but with different APIs) in many ways.  If you want to synchronized threads of execution that are in different processes, a mutex object can be used, while a `CRITICAL_SECTION` object cannot.

So to answer your question (I think), if you are only concerned with protecting a critical section among threads that are part of the same process, a `CRITICAL_SECTION` object should be adequate. A mutex object can be used instead, but it may be somewhat less performant. There should be no need to use both types of objects